# Binary encryption puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

There are 8 rooms, one containing a pot of gold. You know which room the gold is in, but your partner does not. The task is to inform your partner which room the gold is in under the following condition.

There is a switch board with 40 up/down switches, all randomly set. You must pass on the room number to your partner using this switch board while only being able to flick one switch.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do I have to flip a switch or can I leave all the switches as they are if I want?

Comment: You can leave all the switches if you want

Comment: Can this be done sothat the partner knows the correct room number with a probability of $100\%$? I'm thinking that a number $x < 8$ can be represented with $3$ bits in binary. Can we have made plans with our partner to read the first three switches in binary (up=$1$,down=$0$)? The problem is still that we can only control $1$ bit, meaning either the first three bits are correct ($\frac{1}{8}$ chance), or we can correct a $1$-bit error, so for $2$ or $3$ bit errors we're screwed. Maybe the 40bit randomness in the initial setup of the up/down switches can be exploited to convey more information.

Comment: Can the partner see which switch I flick?

Comment: @ajotatxe:  no.  Otherwise you could do it with eight switches-just flip the one that corresponds to the room.

Comment: The partner does not know the switch you flick but a strategy can be discussed before the board is viewed.

Comment: An easy solution is to agree that I arrange the *bitwise XOR sum* $\oplus$ (aka the NIM sum) of the set of those switches numbered 1-7 that are "ON" to point at the correct room. All integers are their own inverses w.r.t. $\oplus$, and $\oplus$ is associative. So if the way those switches are set currently gives $\oplus$ sum $b$, and the treasure is in room $a$, then I shall flick the switch $c=a\oplus b$. After that partner will see the sum $b\oplus c=a$ as they should. I do need 8 switches for this to work, because it may happen that $c=0$ in which case I will flick switch 8.

Comment: ... and a moment's reflection shows that this is exactly the scheme Ross Millikan proposed :-/

Comment: Can we use the Golay code or similar for this?

Answer (score 9):

I can do it with only seven switches.  I need to transmit three bits to my friend.  Bit one is the parity of the number of switches up among $1,3,5,7$.  Bit two is the parity of the number of switches up among $2,3,6,7$.  Bit three is the parity of the number of switches up among $4,5,6,7$.  I examine the initial setting, find the bits that are wrong, if any, and there is one switch I can flip to make the parities right.  If none are wrong, I leave well enough alone as OP said was allowed.  The switch to flip is found by reading the set of errors in binary.

Comment: Ok. Sloppy reading from me.

Comment: By this method can you only select one out of three bits?  So you an transmit rooms 0, 1, 2, or 4?

Comment: @RobertFrost:  no, you transmit all three.  For example, if $1,3,5,6$ are up, bit $1$ is $1$ because three of $1,3,5,7$ are up.  Bit $2$ is zero because two of $2,3,6,7$ are up.  Bit $3$ is zero.  Of the $2^7=128$ positions of the switches, $16$ indicate each room and you can get to some one of the $16$ from any starting position of the switches.

Comment: This seems very efficient. Is there some place I can read some more theory about it?

Comment: @mathreadler:  each list has the numbers which have a 1 in their binary expansion in a particular position.  This makes sure that the intersection of two lists has 1/4 of the switches, the intersection of three has 1/8 and so on, which is the property you really want.  We could renumber the switches any way we want, but the binary was an easy way to make the lists.  Then you just find which bits are wrong in the original position and flip the corresponding switch.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider bit sums mod 2. Number all switches, starting at 0, ending 39, their bit values being $d[i]$ for index $i$. Take relative prime number "steps", for example 2,3,5 calculate initial arithmetic bit sum for these subsets

$$b = [2,3,5]$$

$$a_i= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor39/b_i\rfloor} d[k \cdot b_i] \hspace{1cm} \text{ where } a_i,d[j] \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall i,j\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Denote the truth value for the need to switch bit $a_k$ by $s_k$. An index is then given by:
$$\mod\left(\prod_{i=0}^{\text{len(b)}}(s_i \cdot (b_i-1)+1) , \prod_{i=0}^{\text{len}(b)}b_i\right)$$

We can convince ourselves the minimum index strategy works by evaluating in Octave (or Matlab if it ever implements automatic broadcasting):

```
mod(prod((mod([0:7]',[8,4,2])>=[4,2,1]).*([5,3,2]-1)+1,2),30)'

ans = [ 1    2    3    6    5   10   15    0 ]
```

As we can see for all of the eight cases there will be unique ID to switch so no space for confusion.

Next step if we need efficiency would be to let both sender and receiver implement a number of **sieves**.

There will be redundancy as prime number positions larger than the largest number ($5$ in our example) will be redundant. This would let us skip $7,11,13, 2 \cdot 7 = 14$ and we're down to needing $16-4 = 12$ switches.

Another sieve would be to remove indexes which have any prime in $b$ occuring more than once. This lets us weed out $4=2^2,8=2^3,9=3^2,12=2^2\cdot 3$, then we're down to $12-4=8$ **switches required**.

**And** if we are obliged to flick a switch there is still no problem as $1$ not divisible by any prime in $b$. And if we are not obliged we can remove index 1 too. Finally the solution should not be worse than Ross's ;)

---

Implementation wise we can do this with bit masking with **and** followed by hamming distances ( population count ) and then xoring with 1 in the desired position. ( Just in case Alice and Bob have access to bit logic assembly in the dungeon. )